# Magento 2 not accessing products in DB

Tags: php, mysql, magento

My catalog contains 172 products - they show up correctly on the front end and are displayed in the table at the backend, I have looked in my DB tables using phpmyadmin and all seems to be well, I have 172 records (although I am a designer not a developer - so it would have to be a very obvious for me to see the problem that way)

...however I can not edit any of them - I get a "This product does not exist message".

Creating a new product through the admin panel results in following report:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:72:"Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested";i:1;s:9155:"#0 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Attribute/ScopeOverriddenValue.php(121): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool->getMetadata('Magento\\Catalog...')
#1 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Attribute/ScopeOverriddenValue.php(104): Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue->initAttributeValues('Magento\\Catalog...', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 0)
#2 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/AbstractModel.php(325): Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue->getDefaultValues('Magento\\Catalog...', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#3 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/UsedDefault.php(84): Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel->getAttributeDefaultValue('links_title')
#4 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/UsedDefault.php(66): Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\UsedDefault->titleUsedDefault('links_title')
#5 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Composite.php(81): Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\UsedDefault->modifyMeta(Array)
#6 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/ProductDataProvider.php(68): Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite->modifyMeta(Array)
#7 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(269): Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider->getMeta()
#8 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('product_form', Array, false)
#9 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)
#10 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#11 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#12 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#13 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#14 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#15 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#18 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#19 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#20 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#21 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction.php(71): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#22 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction->execute()
#23 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#27 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#30 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#36 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#37 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#40 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#42 /data/sites/web/brownequipmenteu/www/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#43 {main}";s:3:"url";s:121:"/admin_16fmoi/catalog/product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/3935c8b29e0e01fcbfedaa426bea0abdd73f37e6fc358e2643cbb293e3cd038a/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/
```

I also can not export the products as a csv through the admin - I get the message 'There is no data'.

...nor can I reindex:

```
admin~/www# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Unknown entity type: Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface requested
```

Help!! Where have my products gone?

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps,

step 1. Delete pub/static and var

step 2. run deploy command.

step 3. Give 777 permission to pub and var folder.